# Which/What (kind of) company treats its employees like that?

Tags: idiomatic-language

If meant as a criticism, what is the natural way to phrase this sentence? What would my options be? Thank you.

*What/Which (kind of) company treats its employees like that?*

Comment: Do you want to refer to 'out of all companies' or 'out of a select group of companies'? Pondering that question might help you to choose between 'what/which'.

Comment: out of all companies.

Comment: It's a kind of ***rhetorical question*** where the only expected answer is ***A very bad kind of company**!*

Comment: @user141956 I completely agree. So based on your decision, which do you think is better: 'which' or 'what'?

Comment: Exactly, but what would be the more natural way to phrase the sentence? Thank you.

Comment: 'What', I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you cleared up (mostly by yourself) in the comments, the answer is:

> What kind of company treats its employees like that?

As FumbleFingers said, it's a rhetorical statement since the answer is obvious.

We use 'what' when the question is open; it's an open choice.

> What kind of person would do that?!

> What do you like on your toast in the mornings?

'Which' is used when there is a narrow/limited set of options:

> Which one of you is responsible for this mess?

> Which do you want? The red one or the blue one?

Comment: As an example of where you would use "which": "There are two kinds of companies: ones with unions and ones without. Some companies can fire their employees without warning. *Which kind of* company treats its employees like that?"